# Output is not maintaining order

Tags: c, output

I have following C program. I am not understanding the output of this program:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int find (int a, int b, int c)
 {
     int temp;
     c=a+b;
     temp=a;
     a=b;
     b=2*temp;
     printf("%d %d %d\n", a,b,c);
     return b;
 }

int main()
{
    int x, y, z;
    x=15;
    y=25;
    z=30;

    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", x, y, z, find(x,y,z));

    return 0;
}
```

According to me, the output value should be:

`15 25 30
25 30 40 30`

But why is it:

`25 30 40
15 25 30 30`

Comment: It's not a matter of evaluation order; it's the fact that arguments are passed by value, not reference, in C.

Comment: @Anonymous: This is not a duplicate of that. Function parameter order is not important here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, let's walk the steps of this program:

1. We create and set initial values for `x, y, z`.
2. We call `printf(..., find(x,y,z));`
3. To do the work for that `printf()` call, we will need to **fully evaluate** the `find()` call.

   1. `find()` does some work changing **local** values of some variables named `a, b, c`.
   2. `find()` calls a `printf()` inside it, printing `25 30 40\n`.
   3. `find()` returns with a value of `30`.
4. Now, we actually have the parameters for the original `printf()` call, we can execute it, and it prints `15 25 30 30\n`.

Note that, we can't call the first `printf()` until we have all of the parameters to it. To do that, we need to call `find()` and let it fully evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

First, you modify the parameters `a`, `b`, and `c` inside the the `find` function, which accounts for the modified values in the first line of output. However, those changes are only visible inside the body of `find`; arguments are passed by value in C. The values of `x`, `y`, and `z` in `main` are not affected by the call to `find`, which explains the second line of output.

Put another way, `a`, `b`, and `c` are local variables to the `find` function which are initialized by, but in no other way related to, the values of `x`, `y`, and `z` in `main`.

Before the `printf` in `main` can print its string, it must evaluate all 4 of its remaining arguments, which includes a call to `find`. During the course of calling `find`, `printf` is called again, which accounts for the 3-number output line appearing first.

Comment: I actually don't get it!

Comment: Why do you expect the value of `x` to change just because you change the value of `a` in `find`? Parameter passing just doesn't work that way in C.

Comment: @Scotia웃: If the two answers provided so far are not helpful, could you explain __why__ you think your answer is correct. That way we could point out where any misunderstanding is. Important in this would be the order of `printf()` calls and what you believe the arguments to those calls would be.

Comment: @sharth, Your answer help me to understand the problem :)